# How to reduce the time consuming when i covert a normal image to Sepia colored image?

Tags: android, android-image

I used the following code to convert a normal image to Gray-scale and Sepia colored image.

for **Sepia Color conversion**:

```
public static Bitmap createSepiaToningEffect(Bitmap src, int depth,
            double red, double green, double blue) {
        // image size
        int width = src.getWidth();
        int height = src.getHeight();
        // create output bitmap
        Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
        // constant grayscale
        final double GS_RED = 0.3;
        final double GS_GREEN = 0.59;
        final double GS_BLUE = 0.11;
        // color information
        int A, R, G, B;
        int pixel;

        // scan through all pixels
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
                // get pixel color
                pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
                // get color on each channel
                A = Color.alpha(pixel);
                R = Color.red(pixel);
                G = Color.green(pixel);
                B = Color.blue(pixel);
                // apply grayscale sample
                B = G = R = (int) (GS_RED * R + GS_GREEN * G + GS_BLUE * B);

                // apply intensity level for sepid-toning on each channel
                R += (depth * red);
                if (R > 255) {
                    R = 255;
                }

                G += (depth * green);
                if (G > 255) {
                    G = 255;
                }

                B += (depth * blue);
                if (B > 255) {
                    B = 255;
                }

                // set new pixel color to output image
                bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
            }
        }

        // return final image
        return bmOut;
    }
```

The above code works fine but the problem is it take more time (more than 60 secs). How can i reduce the time consumption. when i convert the image into Gray-scale it takes less than 2 secs. Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ndk for it refer to this git repository git://github.com/ruckus/android-image-filter-ndk.git

Comment: is there any libraries are available for this

Comment: you can also check http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/ it has pure java solutions, but i think using the ndk would process faster

Comment: already i reffed, also i used that code only but it takes more time

Comment: hey try android.graphics.ColorMatrix

Comment: I'm not familiar in this could you give any links with examples